# Confused in mysql query

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables `property_description` and `property_extras`.

Table `property_description` looks like

```
id location price etc etc
1  New York 3000   v    v
```

Table `property_extras` looks like

```
property_id  extras
1           12,14,16,167
```

Well the question is how should mysql query it look to return result only if at least one of extras is matched ?

Comment: You should have one row per extra. Don't store a data structure in a database.

Comment: So is 'id' & 'property_id' a matched set of fields? So they will have the same value right? and you simply want to check if a record exists in 'property_extras' with a matching id? and if so return a result, or else return nothing?

Comment: You mean "one to many" concept ?

Comment: extras is matched with what ?

Comment: What does this have to do with php?

Comment: In search form there is dropdown menu (for property location) input field (for price) and checkboxes (for extras).
Let`s say the user choose New York type price between $2000 and $5000 and choose some extras (garage, swiming pool) which are represent as 12, 14

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should ideally have extras normalized like

```
property_id  extra_id
1            12
1            14
...
```

If you can't convert your database structure into something like this, then you have to do something (terrible) like:

```
SELECT property_id FROM property_extras WHERE
    extras LIKE '12,%' OR extras LIKE '%,12,%' OR  extras LIKE '%,12'
```

Or, If you can insert commas to the start and to the end like `,12,14,...,` as delphist points out, simply:

```
SELECT property_id FROM property_extras WHERE extras LIKE '%,12,%'
```

Comment: I`m still sketching the database design.
So, how should look like query if I use normalized ?

Comment: `SELECT * FROM property_description INNER JOIN property_extras ON property_description.id = property_extras.property_id WHERE extra_id = 12`. You should make sure that each extra is related to each property at most once, that is, there should be no identical rows on `property_extras`. This is much easier to accomplish in a normalized schema, as simple as setting a unique index (or primary key) on both fields.

Comment: Yeah but how should look query if more than one exta is choosen.
For example 12,17,34,19,40,90,19 are choosen.
Should I use AND ?

Comment: you would use IN:  WHERE Extras IN (12,17,34,19,40,90) if you want to find properties that have at least one of the extras, if you want them all then yes AND would be the way to go

Comment: If you want a record that has all of them, there are various ways to do it, one that comes to my mind: `SELECT * FROM property_description WHERE (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM property_extras WHERE extra_id IN(12,17,34,19,40,90,19)) = 7`, but if you need records that has any of them, you could do like Leslie proposes.

Answer (score 2):

While it is possible using the schema as it stands, the right way to solve the problem is to *[normalize your database](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form)*

Answer (score 0):

Can you fill every `extras` row with `,` at start and end of the line (e.g. `,12,14,16,167,`)?

Then this will work perfectly

```
SELECT FROM `property_description` LEFT JOIN `property_extras` WHERE `property_extras`.`extras` REGEXP ',(13|14|166),'
```

or

```
SELECT FROM `property_description` LEFT JOIN `property_extras` WHERE `property_extras`.`extras` REGEXP ',14,'
```

Comment: still there would be flaw for eg. 14 in start and end in two rows, two rows will selected, to be honest, i think database in not properly setup

Comment: You may use `CONCAT (',', property_extras)`, but this is still principally very bad solution.

Comment: Is it reliable to use REGEXP for large data ?
Let`s say if a table property_extra has more than 10 000 000 records ?

Comment: @experimentX 
Can you recommend better database design ?

Comment: yeah, if propetry_extras is in index, @cypher solution will not use index advantage

Comment: @brodo check battal's answer, i think he will help you with query also